# Regex to remove try & catch

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have tried to learn regex a couple of times but never really manage. I would be vary grateful for some help with a regex to find and replace the following :

```
    #Any code
    try
    {
        #Any code

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new ExceptionHandler("", ExceptionType.UnexceptedException, ExceptionSeverity.Error, null, "", ex);
    }
```

The hard part is pobably to get the variation of tabs and spaces to work.

It should match only the above code, nothing else.

Comment: How come that with 5k rep, you ask a question w/o showing any search effort ?

Comment: Did you read my post?"I have tried to learn regex a couple of times". Does a high rep mean that I know regex?

Comment: This is impossible to do reliably with a regex. You can get a quick-and-dirty solution if your regex flavor (which you didn't specify) supports recursion, but this is likely to blow up in your face if there could be comments or strings within your code that might contain keywords or braces or other relevant syntactic elements.

Comment: What kind of environment are we talking about? Editor? If so, which?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://regex101.com/r/xA6gX1/1) could work, but have a backup somewhere, just in case.

Comment: Thought that regex was the same for any environment, as you see I know vary little about regex. In this case its .NET C#.

Comment: You can't solve this only with regex, because of the `any code` blocks you have mentioned. The hard part aren't the tabs and "white spaces", these are in fact the easiest ones, the hard part is to match **exactly** the closing curly braces.

Comment: @ThomasAyoub, that looks nice but I need it to match exacly the "throw new ExceptionHandler("", ExceptionType.UnexceptedException, ExceptionSeverity.Error, null, "", ex);" as well. Else It could delete custom try and catches that should still be left.

Comment: @t0r0X so in regex there is no way to state , match this try, then ignore anything between these two chars, then match this catch exacly?

Comment: The best you can get with regular expressions, in my opinon, is the answer from @thomas-ayoub (see the link in his answer, not in the comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this one:

```
try\s+\{(.*?)\s+\}\s+catch\s*\(.*?\)\s+\{\s+throw new ExceptionHandler\("", ExceptionType.UnexceptedException, ExceptionSeverity.Error, null, "", ex\);\s+\}
```

But **it will fail** if you have a `try/catch` block within another `try/catch` block. You can try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/xA6gX1/3).

Note: Keep a back-up before massive replace.

Comment: Thanks, when using the quick find it with the "Use regular expression" on it says that it findes nothing?

Comment: @Banshee you did check for regex option, didn't you? Which IDE is it?

Comment: When I try the Find all it finds 4 and these are without any code at all between the try and catch. Have set it to the entire solution.

Comment: Hmm I will chek it, Im using Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: It works with Sublime Text but seems to fail with VS2015. I'll take a look @Banshee

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex:

```
try\s*?\{\s*?(.+)\s*?\}\s*?catch\s+?\(\s*?Exception\s*?ex\s*?\)\s*?\{\s*?(.+)\s*?\}
```